# Searching for images matching an ID then copying matched image to a new directory on MacOS using terminal

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, command-line

I have the following files and folders:

./images
./new_images
./ids.txt

In ./images I have many images for example 12345.jpg
In ./ids.text I have a list of ids one per line like this:

12345
67890
abcde
fghijk etc

I am trying to run code in terminal that checks the ID in ids.txt and then if it matches the ID with an image I'm ./images it copies the matched image to ./new_images.

Here is my code:

```
img_dir=./images
new_img_dir=./new_images

if [ ! -d $new_img_dir ]
then
    mkdir $new_img_dir
    chmod -R 755 $new_img_dir
fi

while IFS= read -r id; do
    find $img_dir -maxdepth 1 -iname "$id.*" -print -exec cp -v {} $new_img_dir \;
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "ID: $id"
        echo "Match found and copied to $new_img_dir"
    else
        echo "No match found for ID: $id"
    fi
done < "ids.txt"
```

I get the response:

> ID: 12345 Match found and copied to ./new_images

But the image is never copied to ./new_images

Can anyone please help by looking at my code to see what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Fail on error
set -o errexit

# ================
# CONFIGURATION
# ================
ID_FILE="ids.txt"
IMG_DIR="images"
IMG_NEW_DIR="new_images"

# ================
# LOGGER
# ================
# Fatal log message
fatal() {
  printf '[FATAL] %s\n' "$@" >&2
  exit 1
}

# Warning log message
warn() {
  printf '[WARN ] %s\n' "$@" >&2
}

# Info log message
info() {
  printf '[INFO ] %s\n' "$@"
}

# ================
# MAIN
# ================
{
  # Create directory if not exists
  [ -d "$IMG_NEW_DIR" ] || {
    info "Creating directory '$IMG_NEW_DIR'"
    mkdir "$IMG_NEW_DIR"
  }

  # Read id(s)
  while IFS='' read -r image_id; do
    # Search images
    images=$(
      find "$IMG_DIR" \
        -maxdepth 1 \
        -mindepth 1 \
        -type f \
        -iname "$image_id.*" \
        -print \
        -exec cp "{}" "$IMG_NEW_DIR" \;
    ) || fatal "Unknown 'find' error"

    if [ -z "$images" ]; then
      warn "No match for ID '$image_id'"
    else
      info "Match for ID '$image_id'"
    fi
  done < "$ID_FILE"

  # Change permissions
  info "Changing permissions '$IMG_NEW_DIR'"
  chmod -R 755 "$IMG_NEW_DIR"
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, I appreciate it.

This gives the output: 'WARN ] No match for ID '12345 

when I know there is definitely an image called 12345.jpg

Any ideas on why this is?

Comment: @Roger Can you share more information? Is the image been copied to the new folder?

Comment: No image is copied, it just iterates the ids.txt and prints:

WARN ] No match for ID '12345 

For every line, changing ID on print for each ID in ids.txt.

To confirm it iterates ids.txt and gives a warning log message for each ID without copying any images.

There are definitely images that match the ID and all locations/directories are correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think is the `-print` option that does not work properly. Are you on OS X or Linux? In my Ubuntu machine it works ;/

Comment: I'm on macOS.

It is printing WARN ] No match for ID 'ID_HERE so not finding any matches and therefore not copying any images.

Any new thoughts that can help  

Comment: @Roger I've edited my answer, try now. I think that in MacOS when you use `-exec` it automatically suppress `-print`

Comment: Thanks, @Carlo, it prints:

'WARN ] No match for ID '12345

and does the same for every ID but even though there is a match it does not copy the file to new_images.

I can't understand why

Comment: Strange, I believe there is a problem with your 'find' or your setup is lacking something... Could you please provide further details?

Comment: Thanks @Carlo

I solved it, for some reason my ids.txt file was not formatted correctly so I ran this command to fix it:

`cat ids.txt | tr -d '\r' > new.txt`

Thanks for all the help  